# xcode - constraints isn't working on my xcode

Tags: ios, constraints

[image: picture of my coding in xcode]

I was wondering how I could fix this constraint on my coding. I have tried every option, deleted it, tried again, looked on youtube and everything. However, I can't seem to find a way. Can someone please help?

Comment: were you able to find the solution?

Comment: it does not seem that you have ever added any constraint to you view; at least I can't see a single one on your screenshot; could you point out where you constraints would be, please?

Comment: check below. I linked a photo

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Center the image? Give it a height and width, and either top or bottom constraint. Then next to the pin icon there's an 'align', align it to be centered in container.

Answer (score 0):

Click on each constraint Trailing, leading, top, bottom and then manually enter 0, 0, 0, 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to centre the barbell image, you can right click on the barbell image and drag to the view (superview).  Hold in Shift and Choose Center Horizontally in Container and Center Vertically in Container.  Tap Add Constraints.   Also add the width and height constraints.

[image: Centre image on screen.]

For the background image, you can set top, bottom, leading and trailing space to 0, by typing in the boxes.  Ensure that the spacers are red.  Then tap on Add 4 Constraints button.  The image should have contentMode = aspectFill.

[image: Span image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers. I figured out how to centre it however the writing is not centred anymore. I'm unsure why.

[image can be found by clicking here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0VNI.jpg)

how do I make the writing show, apart of it is cut out.

And

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IwQh.jpg)

the second picture shows that I have added constraints and it is centred however the barbell is far too small. I am unsure why